# Fragment getActivity is null after on onActivityCreated with viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a tabLayout with a viewpager with 5 fragment, i dont know why but in the fifth fragment when i use getActivity() even after onActivityCreated it returns null, when in the other fragments i use it in the onCreateView and it works fine.

My fifth fragment:

```
public  class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private TextView name,losed_bg,winned_bg,played_bg;
private DatabaseReference mdatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private CircleImageView userpic;
private static final int CAMERA=0,GALLERY=1;
private Typeface font;
private Button logout;
private ProgressBar loading;
private ImageView edit_image;
private EditText edit_text;
private AlertDialog.Builder getImageFrom;

public SettingsFragment() {
}

public static SettingsFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mdatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("USERS").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    mdatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            name.setText(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("losed")){

                   //CRASH String spannable = getActivity().getString(R.string.settings_losed)+" "+String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("losed").getValue(Integer.class));
                    losed_bg.setText(spannable);
            }
            else{

                    String spannable =getActivity().getString(R.string.settings_losed)+" "+String.valueOf(0);
                    losed_bg.setText(spannable);

            }

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("winned")){
                    String spannable = getActivity().getString(R.string.settings_winned)+" "+String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("winned").getValue(Integer.class));
                    winned_bg.setText(spannable);

            }
            else{
                    String spannable = getActivity().getString(R.string.settings_winned) + " " + String.valueOf(0);
                    winned_bg.setText(spannable);

            }

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("played")){
                    String spannable = getActivity().getString(R.string.settings_played) + " " + String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("played").getValue(Integer.class));
                    played_bg.setText(spannable);

            }
            else{
                    String spannable = getActivity().getString(R.string.settings_played) + " " + String.valueOf(0);
                    played_bg.setText(spannable);

            }
            if(dataSnapshot.child("profile_pic").getValue(String.class)!=null) {

                getImage();
            }
            else{
                loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                userpic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                userpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        getImageFrom.show();

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SettingsFragment{3ee8ade} not attached to Activity
```

And the activity where i set up the tabLayout

```
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return MainFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 1:
                return GamesFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 2:
                return OfflineFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 3:
                return FactoryFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 4:
                return SettingsFragment.newInstance(0);
        }

        return MainFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return null;
    }
}

mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
                mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
                tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

                for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                    switch (i){
                        case 0:
                            View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_icon_view, null);
                            view1.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_home_white_48dp);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(view1);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_icon_view, null);
                            view2.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.factory);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(view2);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            View view3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_icon_view, null);
                            view3.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.games_icon);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(view3);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            View view5 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_icon_view, null);
                            view5.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nointernet);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(view5);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            View view4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_icon_view, null);
                            view4.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_white_48dp);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(view4);
                            break;

                    }

                }
```

Comment: which line causes the NPE?

Comment: The first one that gets the string with the getActivity

Comment: Change this- return MainFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
to this- return MainFragment.newInstance(position);

Comment: Please show the exact code that causes the error rather than describe it.

Comment: Look at the code, the comment that says error

Comment: @MartinDeSimone did u try what i wrote above?

Comment: Yes, it didnt work

Comment: Is the SettingsFragment showing on the screen at the moment of the crash?

Comment: @mikehc no, it starts in the position 0

Comment: Override onAttach(..) inside SettingsFragment and move the code inside onActivityCreated to onAttach(..). Since, the error says your fragment has not been added yet.

Comment: Does the crash occur as soon as you run the app? or after going to the setting page (Page 5) and the going to the other fragments?

Comment: @mikehc as soon as i run it

Comment: Try the onAttach(..) thing i wrote above because getActivity() returns null unless onAttach(..) is called. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that adds the listener to the database (`addValueEventListener`) to the `OnAttach` method of the fragment. Depending of how you are using the ViewPager, `FragmentPagerAdapter` might decide to "recycle" your fragments. So it's important to remove the database listener when the fragment is detached from the Activity (`OnDetach`).

Seems like the database is a Singleton, so the listener might out-live your fragment or even the Activity. Possibly causing some memory leaks. So remember to remove the listener just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the ValueEventListener, i have tried before overriding onAttach but it didnt work because i didnt use addListenerForSingleValueEvent.